# sql combine multiple where operators

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a query that I am writing in MS-SQL that must check to see if the information about a client is already in the table before inserting it.  If one entity has changed then the row will be inserted.  The questions is can I combine operators in the where clause?  Right now I have a query that looks like this:

```
select * from @Temp c
where exists (select * from Clients c2
            where (c.ClientId = c2.ClientId and c.ClientFName <> c2.FirstName) 
            or (c.ClientId = c2.ClientId and c.ClientLName <> c2.LastName)
            or (c.ClientId = c2.ClientId and c.ClientAddress <> c2.Address)
            or (c.ClientId = c2.ClientId and c.ClientCity <> c2.City)
            or (c.ClientId = c2.ClientId and c.ClientState <> c2.State)
            or (c.ClientId = c2.ClientId and c.ClientZip <> c2.Zip)
```

Is there any advantage or disadvantage to writing the query like this:

```
select * from @Temp c
where exists (select * from Clients c2
            where (c.ClientId = c2.ClientId 
            and (c.ClientFName <> c2.FirstName 
            or c.ClientLName <> c2.LastName 
            or c.ClientAddress <> c2.Address 
            or c.ClientCity <> c2.City
            or c.ClientState <> c2.State
            or c.ClientZip <> c2.Zip)))
```

To me both queries work but what is the best way to write this?

Answer (score 2):

In practice, if you look at the query plans for the two queries, you're likely to find that the optimizer reduces them to the same thing.  If it doesn't, then you'd choose the version that provides the best performance (query plan), but the two are equivalent and the optimizer is likely to notice that and exploit that.

I note that if any of the columns allows nulls, then the comparison for that column is inadequate.  You'd need something more like:

```
OR c1.ClientAddress <> c2.ClientAddress
OR (c1.ClientAddress IS NULL AND c2.clientAddress IS NOT NULL)
OR (c1.ClientAddress IS NOT NULL AND c2.clientAddress IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

Any time you can eliminate redundancy, that's a good thing.  The second way wins. :)

BTW, let's answer the better question that you didn't ask, assuming that `@temp` was loaded from `Clients` so that you could find problematic records.  You could have done:

```
SELECT * FROM Clients
WHERE clientid in (
    SELECT clientid from ( select distinct * from Clients ) t
    GROUP BY clientid HAVING count(*) > 1 )
```

(this also eliminates the mess of comparing for `null`s)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what the exact question is here. But, both look fine - I prefer the second one from a readability point of view but thats preference.

Performance wise, I dont think your going to notice a difference.